# where to find the ancestor version of a package?

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, package, ancestor

When a new package version is created, an ancestor version is associated with it. Now, after several releases, we want to roll back some changes and we need to know the ancestor version associated with each of our releases. How on earth do you get that useful information?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pkg2_dev.meta/pkg2_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_view_ancestors.htm

For completeness, the following command will print the ancestry tree for your package:

```
sf package version displayancestry --package 04tV.....
```

Something like this:

```
└─ 1.1.0.3
   └─ 1.1.1.1
```

Comment: I must mention that this does not always work. Sometimes you will get the error 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')'